# How to run hotstar in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and running the latest version of chrome still hotstar is not working? how to recover from that 
I have tried the methods discussed on the ubuntu forums still hotstar is not working

Comment: This is not a programming question. I suggest you delete this and post a new question on [ubuntu.se]. Don't assume that readers know what "hotstar" is, and please provide more detail than "not working".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming. Also not the right site to ask.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with the Flash player that Hotstar is using. 
Using any other media player for viewing their streams should work just fine.

I have hosted a version using the open sourced Flowplayer here:
http://playhotstar.madhavanmalolan.com

All the magic is in the javascript, feel free to view source for more details!

You don't need to install any software of plugins.

Comment: page is showing welcome to express that's it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the user-agent to anything except ubuntu, lets say nexus 7. Works as a charm then.

To change the user agent:

You can install the User-Agent Switcher for Google Chrome extension(User-Agent Switcher for Google Chrome) and select the desired user-agent(nexus 7 works for me).

Comment: didn't work for me.

Comment: didn't worked for me too

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution

1. Download google chrome in ubuntu and install it
2. Go to chrome web store.
3. Add "user agent switcher" extension from web store
4. Click on the user agent switcher extension beside the url bar.
5. Click on the default .
6. Select Nexus 7 (tablet).[User agent Switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U92VF.png)
7. Now go to hotstar.

This works for me.
If it doesn't work try updating adobe flash player.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore

Comment: @KhurshidAlam I edited the solution. See if it works for you

Answer (score -6):

Here is the solution I have found.

Step  1 : Copy the video url

(Ex. : http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/icc-champions-trophy-2017/m181413/live-streaming/2001702409)

Step 2 : Add **sudo** before hotstar

Ex. http://www.sudohotstar.com/sports/cricket/icc-champions-trophy-2017/m181413/live-streaming/2001702409

Step 3 : hit enter. It should start playing that video.

Comment: on chrome, I got `www.sudohotstar.com’s server DNS address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Comment: Nice joke but not a place to do the same

Comment: @SagarRohankar : don't go to home of hotstar, instead open your link first you want to watch then add sudo at beginning.

Comment: @dineshkandpal I know it sounds like a prank but it was actually working for a few weeks. The domain however wasn't owned by hotstar